# @EnableWebMvc annotation changes response encoding

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, character-encoding, http-headers

By default, my Spring Boot application responds to any request with the following Content-Type headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

I believe this has been so from the beginning and I would like to keep it this way.

However, by making a simple change and only adding `@EnableWebMvc` to my `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, the `charset` attribute is changed:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

And so the UTF-8 encoded content of the response is displayed incorrectly on the website.

Comment: I would prefer not to add `produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"` into the `@RequestMapping` annotation of every single controller method in the application.. There must be a better way.

Comment: `@EnableWebMvc` disables all of Spring Boot's auto-configuration which is probably not what you want to do. What were you trying to do when you added it? There almost certainly is a better way, but without knowing what you were trying to achieve, it's hard to offer concrete advice.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I added it on a class which implements `WebMvcConfigurer` in order to override the `addInterceptors` method and add my custom interceptor with post-processing and after-completion methods.

Comment: Basically, I want to implement my own `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is what I was saying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to add `@EnableWebMvc` to a class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`. If you want to add an interceptor, making your `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation available as a bean is sufficient. You can do that by annotating the class with `@Component` (assuming its package is covered by classpath scanning) or by returning an instance of it from a `@Bean` method on a `@Configuration` class.